# Editar Sin Afectar el Historial de Inventario con MySql y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7, php5

Estoy haciendo un app inventario con php y mysql para la base de datos y tengo el siguiente problema:

En una base de datos mysql tengo la siguiente tabla `Articulo`

```
id  articulo    precio
1   Bolsa 05Kg    17
2   Bolsa 30Kg    40
3   Agua Torreón  35
```

A partir del mes de agosto el precio de `Agua Torreón` será $45, quiero que al editar el precio se genere el cambio de agosto hacia adelante y que de julio para atrás se mantenga como estaba $35. Ya que al momento de mostrar el inventario por decir de julio la información mostrada no es correcta ya que cambio el precio del articulo en la tabla y lo que deseo es que el cambio del precio solo se vea reflejado a partir de agosto ya que en ese mes fue en donde se realizo el cambio.

[image]

Hasta el momento solo tengo la transacción update para hacer el cambio en la base de datos.

```
$precio = 40;
$id = 3;

UPDATE articulo SET precio = $precio WHERE id = $id;
```

Ojala que me haya dado a entender con esto.

Comment: Nos muestras que has intentado por favor?

Comment: además de lo anterior tu tabla cuenta con alguna columna que permita identificar dicha fecha?

Comment: @Aprendiz no tengo ninguna columna que permita identificar la fecha

Comment: Lo que te comento va en función, de que entonces no comprendo como en tu inventario identificas o identificarías la fecha

Comment: Cómo obtienes las columnas de las fechas?, Igual por ahí podemos llegar a la solución

Comment: @Aprendiz te refieres a la información que se muestra de cada día??

Comment: Por lo que comentas el modelo de datos no es correcto para lo que quieres. La tabla artículo te define ya de por sí el precio sin condiciones (siempre será ese precio). En tu caso creo que deberías remodelar esto extrayendo el precio a otra tabla relacionada con el artículo, indicando en la nueva tabla el precio y las fechas de validez.